# pdfcrop crops too much or too little for some figures

Tags: pdfcrop

I am on Windows 10, with `pdfcrop` 1.40 installed.
For some figures, `pdfcrop` works fine, but not for others.

For figures like [this one](https://github.com/bixiou/global_tax_attitudes/raw/main/figures/OECD/Heatplot_global_tax_attitudes_GCS_positive.pdf) it does not crop anything:
[image: Figure for which pdfcrop does not crop anything]

While for figures like [this one](https://github.com/bixiou/global_tax_attitudes/raw/main/figures/country_comparison/belief_mean-non-crop.pdf), it crops too much:

Non-cropped figure: [image: Non-cropped figure]
Cropped figure: [image: Cropped figure]

Any idea how to make `pdfcrop` work fine?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes something like *invisible* lines cause wrong cropping. Sometimes BoundingBox information in the PDF cause wrong cropping. `pdfcrop` has extra options, to fix such PDFs manually. E.g. for [the first image](https://github.com/bixiou/global_tax_attitudes/raw/main/figures/OECD/Heatplot_global_tax_attitudes_GCS_positive.pdf) you can use:

```
pdfcrop --bbox "23 52 396 242" Heatplot_global_tax_attitudes_GCS_positive.pdf
```

to reduce the size.

[The second image](https://github.com/bixiou/global_tax_attitudes/raw/main/figures/country_comparison/belief_mean.pdf) seems to be cropped already. So you don't need to run `pdfcrop`. But if I use

```
pdfcrop belief_mean-crop.pdf
```

I get the same size as the original PDF. So it seems to be correct.

However, you could experiment with options `--margins` and `--noclip` to increase the cropping result again.

BTW: The result of `pdfcrop` also depends on ghostscript. So if the syntax of ghostscript changes a lot, the `pdfcrop` also could break. I'm currently using ghostscript version 9.56.1.

Comment: Thank you. For the first one, I'd like to find a solution that does not rely on customizing the parameters manually, if possible. For the second, I attached the wrong link (it is now corrected). Indeed, meanwhile I had a friend of mine running pdfcrop so that it works fine (for him it works but not for me). In a nutshell, the problem remains.
How do you find your ghostscript version?

Comment: @bixiou run ghostscript option `--version` only to get the version.

Comment: OK. Ghostscript is not in my path, can this cause the bug? I found it in C:\texlive\2022\tlpkg\tlgs\bin\ and C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\LyX 2.3\ghostscript\bin (running `gswin64c --version` in these folders show that my version is 9.56.1).

Comment: Btw, my friend for whom it works is on Mac OS, with GhostScript version 9.55.